# Question on the sequence bounded away from $0$

Tags: analysis

> **Definition 5.3.12** (Sequences bounded away from zero). A sequence $(a_n)_{n=1} ^∞$ of rational numbers is said to be bounded away from zero iff
> there exists a rational number $c > 0$ such that $|a_n| ≥ c$ for all $n ≥ 1$

> the sequence 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, . . . is not bounded away from zero

This definition comes from Analysis I textbook of Tao, My question is: Take the sequence mentioned for example, Does $|a_n| ≥ c$ for all $n ≥ 1$ mean that  $a_n=0$ when $n \to \infty$? $(a_1=0.1,a_2=0.01...)$

Sometimes it drives me crazy thinking about the term of a sequence consisting entirely of positive numbers will eventually equal to zero. I know it's the area of limit issue,but when I just think about it, it's just against my intuition.

(Pardon me that I'm a fresh man to real analysis,and maybe I just need time to accept this 'against-intuition'.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very important to understand that the limit of a sequence is not necessarily a value the sequence will ever actually reach, but it's a value you can get arbitrarily close to. So saying $a_n \rightarrow 0$ means that the terms of the sequence get very small, but it doesn't necessarily mean that there's any value of $n$ for which $a_n = 0$. Taking the example sequence $0.1, 0.01, \ldots$ we would say that $a_n > 0$ for all values of $n$, but $a_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Note that the example sequence is one that is *not* bounded away from zero. If a sequence *is* bounded away from zero, then that means you can put a "barrier" of width $c$ around zero, and the sequence will *never* go inside that barrier. For example, the sequence $\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{4}, -\frac{4}{5}$ is bounded away from zero - you can show that $|a_n| = \frac{n}{n+1} \geq \frac{n}{2n} = \frac{1}{2}$, and so every term sits outside the barrier of $(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$.

By comparison, consider the sequence $0.1, 0.01, 0.001, \ldots$. Suppose that it *was* bounded away from zero, i.e. we could find a rational number $c$ such that $|a_n| \geq c$ for all $n$. But since $c$ is rational, we can write it as $\frac{p}{q}$, but then that means we can find a number $k$ such that $c > \frac{p}{10^k} \geq \frac{1}{10^k} \geq |a_k|$, in other words we've found a term of the sequence that snuck inside the barrier, which contradicts our assumption that the sequence is bounded away from zero.

Comment: Thank you @ConMan

Comment: +1. It's important for a student to understand that a numerical sequence is not a sequence of events occurring in time, and the terms are not in some process of becoming something other than what they already are.

Answer (score 0):

Per your question, the answer is no. For example, take the sequence $a_n = \dfrac{n}{2n-1}$ of rational numbers. This sequence is bounded away from $0$ as there is a $c = \dfrac{1}{3}$ and we have: $a_n > c, \forall n \ge 1$. Also $a_n$ does not tend to $0$ when $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can prove this by making contradictions. Assume what you said is true: $a_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\to \infty$, when $n$ is large, $a_n$ is arbitrarily close to $0$, which means $a_n<c$ after some sufficiently large $N$. But this contradicts with $|a_n|\ge c$. So the assumption is false.